# can i connect client server(localhost:8082) and websocket(localhost:8080)?

Tags: websocket, spring-websocket

My problem is I need to connect different port or server!
websocket server(localhost:8080) client server(localhost:random)
(failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403)
why?? I'm tired...

I already tried same port and I can success!
I can connect client(localhost:8080) and websocekt(localhost:8080).

I want to use websocket using (server side: java sts, tomcat 8.0).

questions
1. websocket can connect only same server and port???!!!!(no! please!)
2. If I can... what's the problem :(? Do u have any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(myHandler(), "/myHandler").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler myHandler() {
        return new MyHandler();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is related to CORS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing. 
I assume you are using spring websocket as you didn't mention.

You will need to disable same origin policy in your websocket config class as below example,

@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

```
@Override
protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {

}

@Override
protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
    //disable CSRF for websockets 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: i can insert your class(WebSocketSecurityConfig)!

Comment: i can insert your class(WebSocketSecurityConfig)! but.. cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/messaging/access/intercept/ChannelSecurityInterceptor error... i don't know how to set servlet about security.. help me..

Comment: add the security messaging dependency to your POM

Comment: add the security messaging dependency to your POM
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
 </dependency>

Comment: I was able to solve the problem yesterday.
Your help is so me... thanks.

Comment: Your help is so me... thanks. Solving way almost same. please below code